# merge() in R is not returning the desired result

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have dataframes called exp and cat which are to be merged.
Here are the dataframes:

```
> exp
   keyword keyword2
1      SLD      SLD
2  TRUNION   GANTRY
3     PCON      LVA
4      SLD      SLD
5   GANTRY     GCON

> cat
            keyword category
1                PA      11-113
2                IQ      151-16
3              GCON      25-11
4              PCON      29-11
5               HVA      12-41
6               LVA      22-31
7              HCON      21-40
8                LR      2-50
9                TP      12-16
10              CID      25-66
11               HD        31
12              LLD      35-10
13              SLD      37-12
14              RTT      3-26
15          TRUNION      31-35
16           GANTRY      13-15
```

But upon merging these two dataframes, I am getting only NAs.
Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Here is the function and its output:

```
>merge(exp,cat, by='keyword',all.x = TRUE)

   keyword keyword2 Category
1     PCON      LVA     <NA>
2      SLD      SLD     <NA>
3      SLD      SLD     <NA>
4  TRUNION   GANTRY     <NA>
5   GANTRY     GCON     <NA>
```

Comment: can you dput exp and cat?

Comment: @ZahiroMor, totally agrre, that would be better, although `read.table("clipboard")` works well here. @ SowmyaT.K, what is your desired outcome? Does `cat[ cat$keyword %in% exp$keyword, ]` do the job? By the way, don't use `cat` as a variable name, it's a reserved word.

Comment: yeah. i changed the variable name to cat1. But still, output is filled with NAs. Yeah. i will check out with dput(). thank you

Comment: @vaettchen `cat` is not a reserved word in R. It's just a name of a `base` function (as well as `exp`).

Comment: > dput(exp)
structure(list(keyword = structure(c(15L, 17L, 12L, 15L, 22L), .Label = c(" CID", 
" ECG LEADS", " GCON", " HCON", " HVA", " IQ", " L-ARM", " L ARM", 
" LIGHT RAIL", " LLD", " LVA", " PCON", " PPM", " RELO", " SLD", 
" SNAC", " TRUNION", " TRUNNION", " UPS", "COVERS", "ELECTRICAL", 
"GANTRY", "HARDWARE", "ROTATE", "TOUCH PAD", "TOUCHPAD"), class = "factor"),keyword=.....), .Names = c("keyword", 
"keyword2"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")  ........this is the output of dput(exp)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error.  The following code works for me:

```
exp <- data.frame(keyword=c("SLD", "TRUNION", "PCON", "SLD", "GANTRY"), keyword2=c("SLD", "GANTRY", "LVA", "SLD", "GCON"))

cat <- data.frame(keyword=c("PA", "IQ", "GCON", "PCON", "HVA", "LVA", "HCON", "LR", "TP", "CID", "HD", "LLD", "SLD", "RTT", "TRUNION", "GANTRY"), category=c("11-113", "151-16", "25-11", "29-11", "12-41", "22-31", "21-40", "2-50", "12-16", "25-66", "31", "35-10", "37-12", "3-26", "31-35", "13-15"))

merge(exp, cat, all.x=TRUE, by="keyword")
  keyword keyword2 category
1  GANTRY     GCON    13-15
2    PCON      LVA    29-11
3     SLD      SLD    37-12
4     SLD      SLD    37-12
5 TRUNION   GANTRY    31-35
```

It would help if you use dput() to provide your actual `exp` and `cat`.  Then we can more likely figure out what's going on.  I notice that `Category` is capitalized in your merged df but not in cat, so I suspect there's another step you've done in between (perhaps inadvertently) that you've not shared.

Comment: No. While editting the question here, it has become capitalized accidentally without my notice. The output shows lowercase category only. thank you.

Comment: the first dataframe actually have more than 1k rows. i have just extracted 5 rows to a dataframe exp.

Answer (score 0):

If your `exp` dataset is lowercase, then convert to upper and merge,

```
exp <- as.data.frame(sapply(exp, toupper))
merge(exp,cat, by='keyword',all.x = TRUE)
#  keyword keyword2 category
#1  GANTRY     GCON    13-15
#2    PCON      LVA    29-11
#3     SLD      SLD    37-12
#4     SLD      SLD    37-12
#5 TRUNION   GANTRY    31-35
```